# Dotnet restore gives 301 error for a NuGet package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

My code was working fine last night but when I tried to restore it today using `dotnet restore`, I get the following error.

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.ui/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fluentvalidation/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
  Failed to download package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.3.1.8' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/3.1.8/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.3.1.8.nupkg'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
  Failed to download package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.3.1.1' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.entityframeworkcore/3.1.1/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.3.1.1.nupkg'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.embedded/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.sinks.console/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.text.regularexpressions/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 301 (Moved Permanently).
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and my dotnet configuration is as follows

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.414
 Commit:    88a3b0c5ca

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.414/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.20
  Commit:  2833dab8c3

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.414 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

However, if I try to directly access the URLs, I am able to access them? I'm also using a VPN. Could this be due to that?

Comment: Did this start working for you just now? Seems like a temporary outage? The only actions I took was update VS 2022 and VS 2019

Comment: Got the same problem with DotNet 3.1 from their official docker image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk, only from the `dotnet restore` command. Retry may work. Started a few days ago.

Comment: It was working fine yesterday but I started getting this error about 2 hours ago. Is there a temporary way to fix this other than waiting and retrying?

Comment: check your package sources, leave only one active, if this will not help, you can copy-paste these packages (the best option copy from your teammate). also  create a new empty project, add a few dependencies, build

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix my problem like this:

1- download Nuget.exe from [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)

2- add Nuget.exe to the windows path ( you can copy it in c:/windows/system32)

3- open the command line and navigate to your solution folder and run this command:

> nuget.exe restore -DisableParallel

hope it works.